# How to Instruct OSS ASN.1 tool to Generate the codec Only for NB-IoT Specific Messages

Tags: c, tags, asn.1

Is there any way to instruct OSS ASN.1 tool to generate the codec only for NB-IoT specific messages?, as the manual clean up is bit tedious and inappropriate way of generating asn libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking a question about a particular ASN.1 Compiler vendor's tool, this question would be better addressed by sending mail to the tool vendor's technical support team.  I happen to work for OSS Nokalva, so I can tell you their support team can be reached by sending mail to support@oss.com.  It is best not to manually edit the ASN.1 specification since it is easy to inadvertently alter the UNALIGNED PER encodings, resulting in interoperability problems.